# Multi monitors not working in 18.04 amd rx550

Tags: amd-graphics

As I'm booting up my computer, both monitors work. I see the Asus logo in both screens. I also see Ubuntu's purple loading screen after that.

However, right when it prompts me to login, the 2nd screen stops working. It's as if the OS is putting it to sleep.

Any ideas how to fix this?

AMD Radeon RX550, Ubuntu 18.04.1, using the HDMI and DVI ports.

Radeon Drivers 18.3 in use. Kernel 4.18

EDIT 1 - Been googling for 2 hours. Seems like this issues has been going on for almost a decade. How is there not a simple fix for this? (not amdgpu specific issue, just the monitor going into power save mode after boot)

EDIT 2 - xrandr add mode and output auto don't fix anything.

Comment: Were you having a problem with the 4.15 kernel that comes default with 18.04.1?

Comment: I thought I fixed this with amdgpu.dc=0 because the 2nd monitor worked great. But the HDMI audio stopped working. radeon audio flag did nothing to fix that.

Comment: Also, no idea if this was an issue in 4.15. I didn't try it when that kernel was installed.